# Need to play audio file but not allow downloading

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, streaming

I'm building an ASP.NET application where I need to play audio files, but disallow downloading of the file itself. It's an intranet site so I can use AD to restrict direct access to the files to everybody but my web service account, so I'm covered from that angle.

I'm currently leaning towards building a handler that encrypts the audio file and provides it to a Silverlight applet that decrypts and plays. Is this a reliable approach, or is there an easier way to do this? It seems the big players like Netflix use a streaming server to protect their content, but that definitely is not in our budget.

Comment: In general, if a remote system can access the data for one purpose, it can access the data for any purpose. You can employ tricks to discourage downloading (check HTTP headers for specific values, strip/mangle MP3 headers, which are reconstructed by the client, etc.) But again  if the client can use your data to play music, if they try hard enough, they can save it as well.

Comment: That's why I was going to try to encrypt the stream on the server, and decrypt on the Silverlight client. I was hoping to mitigate the chance of this happening. My explanation back to the client is that if somebody really wants the audio, they can record it through the speakers from their smartphone.

Comment: Encryption doesn't really add much, because you could reverse-engineer a static key out of the client, or snatch it out of memory with a debugger. I'm not suggesting you do *nothing*, I'm just pointing out that this is nearly impossible to solve perfectly.

Comment: I would at least check the User-Agent string, and make sure it's that of your client. This will prevent a simple URL download. Going further, you could implement a simple hash-based challenge-response that would prevent all but the most diligent attackers from accessing your content.

Comment: True. I'm really looking for obfuscation instead of prevention. I'd like to try to devise a way to discourage this behavior on a mass level. Everybody using the system is an employee and has signed paperwork about improper use of data.